# Foundation 4 top bar dropdown not dropping down

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I'm not exactly sure what's going on but anybody with experience with the framework might be able to help, here's the page:
http://broadcasted.tv/testdesign.php

And this is the code (which seems to be okay according to this http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/top-bar.html):

```
 <li class="has-dropdown">
        <a href="#">Main Item 3</a>

      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="#">Dropdown Level 1a</a>


        </li>

      </ul>
  </li>
```

Anybody can tell me what the problem is ?

Comment: did you link necessary js files??

Comment: I added `jQuery(document).foundation('orbit',{
            timer_speed: 3000
        });` and it breaks the top bar. Not using gems. Calling dropdown by the same method does not work either.

Answer (score 2):

LOL!!! I was having the same issue. Added the Lib, and checked everything. Then I realized I did not initialize the foundation on page ready. I had orbit slider and dropdown on that page so had to initialize both.
$(document).foundation('dropdown');
$(document).foundation('orbit');

you can initialize everything with 
$(document).foundation();
but I prefer to micromanage my code :)

Hope this help.

Comment: been reading the docs and playing with the css for a week and just now got to dropdowns...somehow I went this whole time and never even realized I needed to initiate (or even include for that matter) the js. I was only using their css and everything was fine until now lol. Anyway, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

You need to link the javascripts

make sure you have linked jquery, foundation javascript file, and app.js etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your js files.
Every time you update your gem also need to update your js files.

Answer (score 0):

I tried @talha's suggestion, but didn't work. 
I was using Foundation 5 and using the following code helped me out. Try it:

```
 <script>
$(document).foundation('topbar');
  $(document).foundation('orbit',{
    //orbit options
  });
</script>
```