# Foundation Top-bar dropdown not working

Tags: html, zurb-foundation, css

I've been trying to get a menu have a dropdown menu, however all I get is this (the history link is supposed to be a dropdown menu under the about tab): 
[image]

I've included in all the javascript files, and initialized them and I really can't understand what's going on. Any ideas? Website link: http://mvcsf.com/new/

Code:

```
<nav class="top-bar">
                <ul class="title-area">
                    <img src="img/logo.png">
                </ul>
                <ul class="right">
                    <li><a href="">home</a></li>
                    <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="">about</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li>history</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>                        
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Foundation 4 top bar dropdown not dropping down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231074/foundation-4-top-bar-dropdown-not-dropping-down)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're missing your section tags before your "right" ul.

```
<nav class="top-bar">
    <ul class="title-area">
        <img src="img/logo.png">
    </ul>
    <section class="top-bar-section">
        <ul class="right">
            <li><a href="">home</a></li>
            <li class="has-dropdown"><a href="">about</a>
                <ul class="dropdown">
                    <li>history</li>
                </ul>
            </li>                        
        </ul>
    </section>
</nav>
```